# Supervisord and Ruby: Can't find ruby_executable_hooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, supervisord

I'm trying to configure supervisord to run my ruby app.
The app runs fine when I do ./manage.py runserver
So I'm guessing the problem is about paths.

This is the error I get:
`/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No existe el fichero o el directorio`

This is my supervisord conf:

```
[program:myapp] 
directory=/home/myapp/production
command=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/bundle exec rails server -d
environment=RAILS_ENV="production",PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/u$
autostart=true 
autorestart=true 
user=myuser 
chown=myuser:mygroup
chmod=0660
```

Can someone detect the error here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you need to set many more environment variables to make it work. You can use `printenv` to check which ruby variables are in your environment and then set them in your supervisor configuration.

I use `rvm` for having something like `virtualenv` but for ruby (https://rvm.io/).

Here is my environment variables for a ruby project that I have:

```
environment=RAILS_ENV="development",HOME="/home/ubuntu",PATH="/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin",GEM_HOME="/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551",GEM_PATH="/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global",MY_RUBY_HOME="/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551"
```

The variables that I set are `RAILS_ENV`, `HOME`, `PATH`, `GEM_HOME`, `GEM_PATH`, and `MY_RUBY_HOME`. Maybe you won't need all of them, but you should check that.

Comment: Nope, sorry.
I added all the env vars you mentioned and I still get the same message. So we can rule that out.
I do have rvm installed, but I'm not sure I'm using it correctly, I will check that out.